how to connect blinks action to my program
I wrote a program integrating token 2022, then I deployed devnet. I want to connect blinks actions to my program. Can someone give me a little suggestion?

Here is the link to the Solana Actions and Dialect Blinks. If you have a specific question, please feel free to ask after reading the docs. They contain examples and boilerplates to get you started. https://solana.com/docs/advanced/actions https://docs.dialect.to/documentation/actions/blinks

@SalSamani thank you so much
